# Actually **Delete** service while services.msc is open

Tags: delphi, winapi, service

I've noticed that `sc delete ServiceKeyName` won't work if `services.mmc` is open. It marks it for deletion (whatever! That just means it doesn't do what I want as far as I'm concerned).

My question is: Is there a method for deleting a service that will work regardless whether `services.mmc` is open or not? or should I ensure any instances of `services.mmc` are closed before I try to delete it?

I'm looking into using `DeleteService`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682562%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682571%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

But it also talks of closing handles and similar excuses for why it cannot do what the user has asked to be done **immediately**. So if `DeleteService` is going to also require that `services.mmc` is closed, then I'll stick to `sc delete` and kill process on `services.mmc` instead of implementing `DeleteService`. I want a method that does what it advertises (no excuses - no waiting for anything).

Comment: We de-install services all the time (switching between versions of our suite) with the services.mmc open. Haven't looked into DeleteService, but I thinkg it would indeed be just a matter of stopping the service first.

Comment: Hi Marjan, oh we stop the services too, but which method do you use to stop them ("sc stop" or ControlService(.., SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ..), and do you have a delay after the service uninstallation (eg sleep(3000)) or do you execute the reinstallation straight away?

Comment: Uh, we stop them via the services.mmc or via a net stop command. We re-install using the new exe which recognizes a /reinstall commandline parameter (vs install or uninstall). The re-install does a Uninstall/Install sequence which boils down to OpenService/DeleteService, followed by a CreateService, so it is rather immediate :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this you would need the services MMC snap in to close and reopen its handle to the service control manager. It won't do this and thus you have to accept the behaviour as is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing. If you pass the command `-remove` after the service name, it will remove it even if the `services.mmc` is is open. Also stop the service first via command line `net stop 'servicename'` prior to the `-remove`.